# Mongoose suddenly returning empty []

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Been following trying to get a mongoose server setup, and it briefly worked, but now it's not for some reason and I honestly have no idea what's going on. No matter what I do, it's returning a blank []?

Collection is "users" all lowercase. Config is in other files. Like I said it has worked before for me briefly and I have no clue why it suddenly stopped.

EDIT - The user object is undefined so it's not even pulling the data from the db for some reason?

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080"
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

const db = require('./app/models')
db.mongoose
  .connect(db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database!");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
    process.exit();
  });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to server." });
});

require("./app/routes/user.routes")(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

model

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
    var schema = mongoose.Schema(
      {
        id: Number,
        ref: String,
        name: String,
        achieves: Array,
        total: Number
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
  
    schema.method("toJSON", function() {
      const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
      object.id = _id;
      return object;
    });
  
    const User = mongoose.model("users", schema);
    return User;
  };
```

findAll method in controller

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  const name = req.query.name;
  var condition = name ? { name: { $regex: new RegExp(name), $options: "i" } } : {};

  User.find(condition)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving users."
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you checked name is not null or undefined?

Comment: @AbdurrahimAhmadov I tried outputting User.data and it's undefined, so it doesn't even look like it's putting in the collection for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one at query:

```
{name: {$regex : `.*${name}.*`, $options: "i"}}
```